# MQRC_OBJECT_ALREADY_EXISTS when WMQ FTE transfer is invoked via ANT script

Tags: ant, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

While trying to invoke a transfer using ANT script I received the below error :

"An internal error has occurred. Product failure data was captured in file "FFDC.FTE.log"."

"Attempt to create a reply queue to receive the transfer result has failed."

Can you please find what is the reason for this?

```
com.ibm.wmqfte.wmqiface.WMQApiFailureException: 
  cc=2 rc=2100 op=openTemporaryQueue - MQOPEN (Queue Manager: QUEUEK, 
  Temporary Queue Model: SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE, 
  Dynamic Queue Prefix: REPLY., 
  Open Options: 8196)
```

Comment: "Can you please find whats the reason for this?" - Yeah with some more information. Perhaps if you regaled us with the contents of... THE LOG FILE?

Comment: Cause:      com.ibm.wmqfte.wmqiface.WMQApiFailureException: cc=2 rc=2100 op=openTemporaryQueue - MQOPEN (Queue Manager: QUEUEK, Temporary Queue Model: SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE, Dynamic Queue Prefix: REPLY., Open Options: 8196)
com.ibm.wmqfte.wmqiface.WMQApiFailureException: cc=2 rc=2100 op=openTemporaryQueue - MQOPEN (Queue Manager: QUEUEK, Temporary Queue Model: SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE, Dynamic Queue Prefix: REPLY., Open Options: 8196)

Comment: @ Taspeotis . The above was the error message displyed in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mnemonic for the error is `MQRC=2100 MQRC_OBJECT_ALREADY_EXISTS` which means that when the model queue was opened, the name that was resolved was to a queue that is already defined.  There are a couple of possibilities here.

First question is what queue manager were you connected to when the attempt to open the reply queue was made?  If you were not connected to a QMgr called `QUEUEK` then the open will have resolved to the transmit queue that goes to `QUEUEK`, and which would already exist.

Another possibility is that `SYSTEM.DEFULT.MODEL.QUEUE` has been set to `DEFTYPE(PERMDYN)` in which case the queues may not be deleted and, because there are a finite number of possible temporary queue names and the namespace would be constantly shrinking, a collision has occurred.

The other possibility, which is a distant second to the first two, is that there's a bug in WMQ that caused a collision on the name of two temporary queues.

In order to figure this out, it will be necessary to know which QMgr you are connecting to when this event occurs.  Also, `DIS Q(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE` on that same QMgr.  Then, `DIS Q(REPLY*)` to see how many permanent dynamic queues (if any) are laying about.  Finally, look at the FDC file that was cut to find out the name of the dynamic queue and see if it exists in the output from the previous step.  If after all of this you still do not have a root cause then it's time to open a support ticket with IBM.

Comment: I get the above error while the fte cancel task is invoked via Ant script. 

The cancelling task also fails.

Inspite of the fte cancel request is send , the ftecopy tasks copies all the file.

Comment: @Rob Could you please suggest some links to know more about the mq architecture....

Comment: Done.  See the response to your prior question.  I held off on answering that one since all the links are to IBM docs except for the ones to my own site and articles. Was hoping someone else would chime in with alternative links or info.